# Create reactive selectInput - flexdashboard with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm trying to make a reactive selectInput using Shiny in a flexdashboard document.

1. My first `selectInput` selects the type of Zone in a Marine Park.

   ```
   selectInput("Zone", label = "Marine Park Zoning:",
             choices = c("All", levels(EoTR$MarineParkZone)), selected = "All")
   ```
2. Then I use this input to create a reactive data frame with only the Zones selected in step 1.

   ```
   zone.choices = reactive({
     if (input$Zone=="All"){
     select(EoTR, ReefName, MarineParkZone, MarineParkMgmtSection)
     }else{
     select(EoTR, ReefName, MarineParkZone, MarineParkMgmtSection)%>%
     filter(MarineParkZone==input$Zone)}
   })
   ```
3. Then I try to use this reactive data frame to define my choices for the next `selectInput`

   ```
   reactive({
   selectInput("Reef", label = "Priority Reef:",
           choices = zone.choices()$ReefName, selected = "Arlington Reef (16-064)")
   })
   ```

When I run the document my second input displays a bunch of code instead of the select menu and therefore all the processes based from that selector fail.

Below is some code that will reproduce the problem

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny 
---
```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)

EoTR = data.frame(ReefName=c("Reef1", "Reef2", "Reef3", "Reef4"), 
              MarineParkZone=c("Fished", "Fished", "Un-Fished", "Un-Fished"))

selectInput("Zone", label = "Marine Park Zoning:",
          choices = c("All", levels(EoTR$MarineParkZone)), selected = "All")

zone.choices = reactive({
  if (input$Zone=="All"){
  select(EoTR, ReefName, MarineParkZone)
  }else{
  select(EoTR, ReefName, MarineParkZone)%>%
  filter(MarineParkZone==input$Zone)}
})

reactive({
selectInput("Reef", label = "Priority Reef:",
        choices = zone.choices()$ReefName, selected = "Reef1")
})
```
````

I know it's probably something silly with how I'm defining my reactive input but I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Cheers,

Sam

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution for you:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny 
---
```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)

EoTR = data.frame(ReefName=c("Reef1", "Reef2", "Reef3", "Reef4"), 
              MarineParkZone=c("Fished", "Fished", "Un-Fished", "Un-Fished"))

selectInput("Zone", label = "Marine Park Zoning:",
          choices = c("All", levels(EoTR$MarineParkZone)), selected = "All")

zone.choices = reactive({
  if (input$Zone=="All"){
  EoTR
  }else{
  EoTR %>%
  filter(MarineParkZone==input$Zone)}
})


renderUI({selectInput("Reef", label = "Priority Reef:",
        choices = zone.choices()$ReefName, selected = "Reef1")})

```
````

The problem was with your `selectInput("Reef"...)`, you have set it to be reactive (which is inccorect) **-->** you should rather render it as UI object (`renderUI`).

Comment: Maybe you can help in a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027198/how-to-do-nested-selections-in-shiny-how-to-use-reactive-with-selectinput?