# How to do nested selections selectInput() in RMarkdown with Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

In a snippet of code below from my `RMarkdown` \ `flexdashboard` code with `shiny` , I need to modify the `choices` for the second `selectInput()` function, based on the selection made at the first `selectInput()` function.

```
selectInput('theme', 'Select theme:',
            choices = c(dtThemes$Theme %>% unique()))  

selectInput('question', 'Select Question:', 
            choices = c(dtQuestions$Question %>% unique())) # This works
            #choices = strQuestions)  # This does not work

strQuestions <- reactive({
    nQuestions <- dtThemes[Theme == input$theme, Q2018]
    dtQuestions[nQuestion %in% nQuestions, strQuestion]
})
```

How do I do that?

Encapsulating code in`renderUI()` did not help:

```
  renderUI({
    selectInput('question', 'Select Question:', 
                strQuestions(), width="100%") 
  })
```

Comment: I tried to do how it is done in related post - which is also with `flexdashboard`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975959/create-reactive-selectinput-flexdashboard-with-shiny, have not succeeded yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've further studied this post: [Create reactive selectInput - flexdashboard with Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975959/create-reactive-selectinput-flexdashboard-with-shiny) and was able to figure out how to make my code work:

```
selectInput('theme', 'Select theme:',
            choices = c("All", dt$Theme %>% unique()), selected="All")

dt.subset<- reactive({
    if (input$theme=="All") {
      dt
    }else{
      dt[Theme == input$theme]
    }
  })
 renderUI({
    selectInput('question', 'Select Question:', 
                choices = (dt.subset()$Question ) %>% unique(), 
                selected =  ( (dt.subset()$Question ) %>% unique() )[1]) 
  })

}
```

The trick is that you need to have a default `selected` value. Otherwise,the code crashes.

Note also I'musing `data.table` for `dt`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `updateSelectInput`. Below is a small example where the choices for Option B are a sequence of the length specified in Option A:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   selectInput("A", "Option A", choices = 1:10),
   selectInput("B", "Option B", choices = NULL)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observe({
      choices_B <- seq(as.numeric(input$A))
      updateSelectInput(session, "B", choices = choices_B)
   })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It should work fine within an RMarkdown document, just make sure you specify `runtime:shiny` in the YAML header.